# Does type coercion have anything to do with why dict(c=c) works in Python?

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
c = 3
dict(c=c) # result: {'c': 3}
```

I'm interested to know what's going on here in this constructor. `c` is the name of a variable, but it ends up being a string in the keys of the `dict`. Is this just syntactic sugar, or is there something deeper going on here? I note that the above snippet gives the same as the following:

```
c = 3
d2 = dict()
d2['c'] = c  # same result when printed.
```

Comment: No type coercion; the type of `dict(C=C)["C"]` is still `int`. `dict(B=C)` would work too; that's just how kwargs are handled. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping.

Comment: no, this has nothing to do with type coercion. `dict(c=c)` is using *`c` as a named parameter* which happens to have the same name as the variable in the caller's scope that you are passing to that named parameter. When you use a named-parameter as part of the `dict` constructor, it is always going to end up as a string key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you are passing parameters as named params, i.e. `foo(a=1, b=2)` you are actually passing a dict whose keys are the parameter names (strings), and whose values are the values.

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    print(type(kwargs))

foo(a=2, b=3)
```

prints

> <class 'dict'>

Only strings can go as the keys to `kwargs`. For example, the following will not work:

```
foo(1=2, b=3)  # fails on SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
foo((1,)=2, b=3)   # fails on SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

d = {1:2, 2:4}
foo(**d)  # dict unpacking works, then fails on TypeError: foo() keywords must be strings
```

This does work:

```
d = {'a': 2, 'b': 4}
foo(**d)
```

because the keys are strings

---

In your code, the `dict`'s copy constructor is being called, on a dict created into the `kwargs`.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. I hadn't realised that this is just a special case of named parameters, or that kwargs is a dict. Your answer covered exactly the two bits of info that I was missing.